# Typescript | TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_signature_pad__ is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signaturepad

I'm currently working on an Angular2 project and I'm trying to use a JS library (https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) for signature input.

I've tried using the library as is, with my code as follows:

```
// .ts file
import * as SignaturePad from 'signature_pad';

export class ... {
    private signaturePad: SignaturePad;

    ngOnInit() {
        let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
        this.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
    }
}
```

.

```
// .html file
<div...>
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

and I get the following error when I launch the browser page:
[ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_signature_pad** is not a constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0ve1.png)

I've also tried using dimpu's angular2-signature-pad, but the same error essentially comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have the typings for `signature_pad` (`npm install --save-dev @types/signature_pad`), it has to be imported and used like below as `signature_pad` does not have any exported members and only declares the class `SignaturePad` into the current scope:

```
import 'signature_pad';

// ...
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
this.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
```

Comment: That results in: 
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: SignaturePad is not defined"